# Shortcut to go from a list of selected checkboxes in a filter to only one selected item

Tags: filter, checkboxes

## The problem

The goal is to offer the user a filter control which by default includes all data

[image]

But the user might typically want to only show data from a certain continent or a certain subset. Especially typical is clicking one after eachother through the contintents one by one. Deselecting every item in the list is obviously painful, so what's a good UX solution?

## The current solution

Right not clicking the checkbox will select/deselect a single item, whilst clicking the label will select only that item (and deselect all other items in the list). Once you select only one (or a few items) you can go back to selecting everything with the checkbox next to the title of the filter).

[image]

Considering we explain this behavior actively to our users it's an acceptable solution, but I still have this nagging feeling there must be better solutions out there.

Comment: The behavior shown in the GIF going to be very confusing for the user. The checkbox is the *Call To Action* while the text is its label. They should either have the same action or the text should have no action. 

Under no condition should they result in different actions

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy And that's **EXACTLY** why I am asking for help here. I am looking for a solution which does not end up with more clicks (or slower in general) as our powerusers would hate that, but which removes this unintuitive behavior.

Comment: Yes I agree with @ShreyasTripathy. The interaction is wrong. When you have selected "My filter" and then you click on one of the items, then it should deselect.

Comment: @DimitraMiha So then you do it 'right' and you have a control which no-one will want to use because clicking through all items one by one is going to be hell. And yes, that's a typical behavior we have observed by our users. I am asking in the title in the very first word for a **SHORTCUT** to do that basic thing in a more efficient way. Our solution is efficient but unintuitive, I am looking for a more intuitive solution of similar efficiency.

Comment: I don't think you are following what @Dimitra and I are trying to convey. Let me rephrase:

By default, don't have any checkboxes selected. If the user wants to select all, they will click on the parent one -> One Click

Similarly, if they want to select just one of checkboxes, they will click on that -> One Click

if they want to select 2, then 2 clicks. Which is completely acceptable

If they want to select all but one, then they will click on the parent checkbox, then uncheck the one they don't want - 2 Clicks. Again, very acceptable

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Except that's not acceptable. That's the entire reason we have this problem. Do you honestly think we would go through the trouble of building an advanced feature like this when default behavior would have sufficed? The developer before me developed the current solution, and just like you guys I don't like it. I think it's confusing and breaks too strongly from what a new user would expect. Luckily our application is used by a 'small' set of users who we train ourselves, but none the less I want a more elegant solution. That elegant solution however can not be less efficient.

Comment: Personally I was thinking about moving away from checkboxes entirely or adding some icon behind each item looking like a cross hair which will select only that checkbox. But I was trying to not limit people with my own brainstorm and only present the problem and the baseline.

Comment: @DavidMulder I don't understand why this is not acceptable. My suggestion for you now is to step out of the problem for a moment, because otherwise, you won't be able to solve it.

Comment: @DavidMulder - No matter what control you choose, if the user needs to perform x number of actions which are not related, they will have to click/tap x number of times. There's no magical way of reducing clicks.

In case of a filter, the user is expected pick and choose what they want to get a better result. You can make a **search** intuitive but not a filter because it is dependent upon the user

Comment: @DimitraMiha Because it takes too much time and effort for our users. That's the 'problem' when you have a small set of power users. This isn't some random site on the internet, this is a business application for professionals. That comes with certain requirements when it comes to efficiency which end up stricter than might be typical.

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy Right now in the current version of the application they can do everything in one click. So that's a reasonable baseline. You suggest increasing this to two clicks (for one action: 'show only data for this item').

Comment: I understand your question but it seems your users are having unrealistic expectations from the application. The only other solution I can suggest here is the use of **tags**. Here's an [example](http://imgur.com/AAnZQ5l)

The tags are intuitive in nature and can give one-click results as they are dependent upon what the user has searched for.

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy How can you deselect all tags except one with one click?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy As an example of an alternative solution which looks ugly, but is relatively easy to comprehend and matches the user expectations: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/109005/39821

Comment: @dosxuk - The tags are not replacing the filter. They are separate with more intuitive options. Like there would be a tag like Europe, Asia, Asia-Pacific, etc. that provide one-click filtering options

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy if the tags aren't replacing the filter, how does that help the OP with the UX of their filter selection? They can currently deselect all but a single filter with one click, adding tags doesn't solve that in a more friendly manner.

Comment: Do not forget to use the state "indeterminate" for the checkbox "my filter" :) https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Comment: @Aqua How would that help in his case? Yes. It would help a bit - but the real problem is trying to do too many things without making things clear.

Comment: When not all children are selected, use the state indeterminate on "My filter" can be usefull for the user. For the other part of your problem, I think the feature to select just one item is... Too confusing. It's really quick for a user to deselect all with one click on "My filter" then click on the chidren choosed. That all. The label should always be linked to the input it's really a better thing for accessibility :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen google's Data Studio?
They have a fairly nimble interaction: see enclosed gif.
You can quickly uncheck all, check all, and use the 'only' filter to quickly select just one item from the list. 
You also have quick enumeration to the right of the category name to show how many are selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly unconventional solution that may work better in your case. Add the locations as deletable tags. This works especially well if there are more than the filters you've mentioned. You can then add the tags that aren't selected in the "unselected" section.

By default, you can include all the tags and provide a checkbox to delete all the tags from the selected list. This checkbox can also have a "Select all" option when you have removed all the tags.

[image: I've used this approach in a project before and]

I'd say this is a more elegant solution because firstly, tags are a more concise way to represent selectable data and the option to add or remove the tags are more apparent. Secondly, they provide for a larger click target than your standard checkboxes, making the interactions more effortless.

Comment: I am not sure I like this solution at all (at least in our case), however so far you're the only one who actually showed an understanding for the problem itself, so thanks +1 .

Comment: Haha. Agreed. Basically, this solution works only when there are a number of other tags as well, not just a single section. So I can understand if this may not apply for your case.

Answer (score 1):

How about a long-press or double-click on both the checkbox and the label being used for the deselect-all-others action? So a single click would just toggle the filter as normal, but double clicking / holding the button for more than half a second would select the new filter, then clear the others.

My concern would be about discoverability, but if we're talking about a small number of power users this should be trainable. It would have the advantage of working exactly like a standard one of these filters for new users, and increasing the hitbox for toggling each filter.

Comment: Entirely undiscoverable indeed, but if we would decide to move towards a completely standard solution this would probably be the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the problem here.

If you have a **parent checkbox** (My Filter) for the checkbox group then clicking it *should* toggle between selecting and deselecting all the check boxes. That is the reason why there is a parent check box.

Comment: So clicking the checkbox or the label doing different things is you think good UX?

Comment: I don't follow. The idea here is to make the "My Filter" pane (both the checkbox and the label) a toggle for checking or unchecking all the checkboxes below.

If the user wants to select just one option then he/she would click on "My filters" to uncheck all and then click on the required option.

If the user wants to deselect one option then he/she would click on the option that needs to be deselected.

Comment: So you would recommend to make the label toggle the checkbox and increase the number of clicks when changing the filter from one item to the next from one click to two clicks?

Answer (score -1):

My suggestions are:

- When you have selected "My filter" and then you click on one of the items, then it should deselect that item. Just like the following image.
- Instead of having "Filter" => "All Regions/Areas/Continents/etc"
- Remove "Data from", because it repeats and the user needs more cognitive load in order to read all the continents.
- In your fiddle, I see that when a continent is deselected, the "My filter" is not deselected.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTvQVc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: The Quick & Dirty fiddle was just to get an idea of the main behavior I was describing. Namely that clicking the label and the checkbox does different things. Text labels and polished behavior of course are not the same in a Quick & Dirty fiddle and an actual product... Anyway, so regarding the actual question, you think it's a good idea to split up the behavior of the label and the checkbox?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get why you gave me a negative point? Polished behavior is part of the user's cognitive load, which actually will help the user understand easier how they can select things. I believe that clicking on the label "My filter" is not understood. Because the expected behavior would be to actually select all or deselect all the options. Except that, I think it is an understandable solution.

Comment: This isn't UX review, this is UX stackexchange. When someone is asking about a specific problem you don't start talking about the fact that a fiddle which helps explain stuff isn't polished enough in areas not relating to the actual problem.

Comment: Anyway, here is a GIF of the behavior: https://i.gyazo.com/84a74c9ee9400da55df5f8ddd7dae417.gif , what do you mean with the behavior of clicking on the label of the list not being understood?

Comment: What does my filter mean? It does not provide any information what will happen when the user clicks there. It is not understandable.

Comment: It's just a place holder, just like the list items. My actual application has nothing to do with continents or anything. I am just talking about the interactions in a list of checkboxes to simplify certain typical usage patterns.

Comment: In UX design, there is not such thing as JUST a placeholder. Placeholders show information and help in user's understanding. Content is the key. It is not about being polished or not. It is about helping someone understand how they can do stuff.

Comment: But that Fiddle is not the product. It's the same as me complaining that a mockup isn't designed nicely. Just like a mockup is meant to show the layout of UI components normally and nothing more, that fiddle was meant to *explain* behavior and nothing more. UI component behavior is also a part of UX you know. It was there so that you could understand what the current solution was and what the baseline was for a better solution.

Comment: The question is not about whether or not the labels makes sense, it is explicitly about the issue of having one behaviour for clicking a checkbox label and a different behaviour for clicking the checkbox itself. What the field labels actually are is not relevant to this problem. Please don't critique the UI / Fiddle, critique and provide a solution to the actual problem that was stated.

Answer (score -2):

One idea for a solution would be to show both checkboxes *and* radio buttons. Don't like this solution personally, although I think it's better than the current solution and takes the same number of clicks to achieve all actions. Just wanted to show there are other solutions as well.

*Note:* I didn't draw the group label in the below mockup, but I would of course include that still as a way to deselect/select all.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkWeJO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>